# How do you use addResourcepath() in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, path, shinyjs

I'm struggling to understand how to use the addResourcePath() function from R shiny (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/resourcePaths.html), even despite this apparent solution to someone with a similar question [How do I porperly use addResourcePath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63417399/how-do-i-porperly-use-addresourcepath)

I want to refer to a folder containing several javascript files to be used in my shiny app, but I don't understand what the 'prefix' is supposed to be, nor how to get the 'directory path'. How does one use addResourcePath to give R Shiny access to files in a particular folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a basic explanation in simple words.

Assuming you want to add the file `myScript.js` located in `c:/javascript_files`. The simplest solution would be to copy `myScript.js` to a `www` subdirectory where your app is located. Anything located in `www` can be accessed by the `UI` of your app by using the prefix `/`.

For this example to add your script to the `UI` you can use

`tags$head(tags$script(src="myScript.js")))`

The HTML code generated by Shiny is going to be

`<script src="myScript.js"></script>`

Your browser is going to interpret it as `http://your_site/myScript.js`. Here the prefix is just `/`.

But in the case you want to keep your JS code in the original location (`c:/javascript_files`), you need to make it accessible to the `UI` (front-end) of your app. Since you can not use a URL like `http://your_site/c:/javascript_files/myScript.js`, you need to create a "virtual" subdirectory that is mapping your local directory to a URL directory, that is actually the prefix parameter in `addResourcePath()`.

For this example, lets use as prefix `jscode`. The expression:

`addResourcePath("jscode", "c:/javascript_files")`

is going to create a "virtual" directory named `jscode` to be used in the URL of your app for the local directory `c:/javascript_files`.

The expression:

`tags$head(tags$script(src="jscode/myScript.js")))`

is going to be translated to HTML as

`<script src="jscode/myScript.js"></script>`

which is going to be interpreted by the browser as `http://your_site/jscode/myScript.js`.

If you had a subdirectory like `c:/javascript_files/code_a`, you don't need to add it, you can reference it in the same way like:

`<script src="jscode/code_a/myScript.js"></script>`

The Shiny code to add the `myScript.js` file will be:

```R
library(shiny)

addResourcePath("jscode", "c:/javascript_files")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "jscode/myScript.js"))  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed response @Geovany. So prefix does not actually refer to anything specific, but is just a name you are providing that you will refer to later when you want to pull a file from the location?

Comment: You can see the prefix as an alias to refer to your local directory.

Comment: Very helpful, you did a nice job of explaining the prefix. I flailed around for a long time using the package resource materials and they were useless. Thanks for taking the time to patiently explain to us newbies

Comment: I'm glad to know that the explanation is useful.